# How to combine queue and join on the play command? - Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, youtube-dl

I want my bot to join with the play command so I don't have to type !join and !play to play a music but just !play.
I also want to add a queue system, that let me add songs in queue and plays them automatically when the song end, with the same command (play), but I don't have a clue on how to do it.
Can you please help me???

```
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0' # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)

@bot.command()
async def join (ctx):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return
    else:
        channel=ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()


@bot.command(help="This command plays a song.")
async def play (ctx,*args):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel= server.voice_client
    url=""
    for word in args:
        url+=word
        url+=''

    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url,loop=bot.loop)
        voice_channel.play (player, after = lambda e: print("Player error: %s" % e)if e else None)
        
    await ctx.send(f"Now playing: {player.title}")
```

Answer (score 0):

this will make the bot join with !play command.

```
@bot.command(help="This command plays a song.")
async def play (ctx,*args):
    if not ctx.message.author.voice:
        await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
        return
    else:
        channel=ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
        server = ctx.message.guild
        voice_channel= server.voice_client
        url=""
        for word in args:
            url+=word
            url+=''

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url,loop=bot.loop)
            voice_channel.play (player, after = lambda e: print("Player error: %s" % e)if e else None)
            
        await ctx.send(f"Now playing: {player.title}")
```

Comment: It does work, but I can't use the !play command anymore when it's already connected.